python model to predict future performance
I would like to build a python model to predict how a student will perform on a given math test. I have data relating to each student and also their score on up to 100 previous tests that (each specific) student has taken (as well as exam-specific data - meaning, each question is categorized by type - geometry, algebra, etc - so I have category-specific accuracy percentages as well). How would I go about building such a predictive model?
EDIT: also the class is graded on a curve, so I would ultimately like to predict a student's rank (within the class curve)
